# How to get IP addresses by using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, vagrant, amazon-route53

I have two DigitalOcean Droplets with public and private IP addresses, created by Vagrant and Ansible playbook.
I need to create was_route53 records for each address (two records per droplet)
How I can get addresses into vars to use it in playbook?

Comment: Hi Igor, welcome to SO. What have you tried, and what error is it producing for you? Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a playbook this weekend to do something very similar.
In my case, I create a droplet on digitalocean, save the IP address, and then add a DNS record to AWS.

I hope this helps. Note that the playbook still has some things hardcoded, such as region and size because I have not polished it off yet.

Also, this is the first time I have used ansible with DO and AWS, and it's the first time that I have used the "register" feature to save variables, so this is probably a long way from best practice.

One thing that seems ugly is my hardcoding of my venv python interpreter.
If you are happy to use your system python, then you don't need to worry about that. The problem is that when ansible sees connection: local, it uses the system python, which is a bit odd since the script is running in a venv on the same machine.

You need to `pip install boto3`
and:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.digitalocean
ansible-galaxy collection install community.aws
```

## example playbook

```
---

- hosts: all
  connection: local
  become_user: tim
  vars: #local connection defaults to using the system python
    ansible_python_interpreter: /home/tim/pycharm_projects/django_api_sync/ansible/venv/bin/python3
  vars_files:
    - includes/secret_variables.yml

  tasks:
    - name: create a DigitalOcean Droplet
      community.digitalocean.digital_ocean_droplet:
        state: present
        name: "{{droplet_name}}"
        oauth_token: "{{digital_ocean_token}}"
        size: "s-2vcpu-2gb"
        region: SGP1
        monitoring: yes
        unique_name: yes
        image: ubuntu-20-04-x64
        wait_timeout: 500
        ssh_keys: [ "{{digital_ocean_ssh_fingerprint}}"]
      register: my_droplet

    - name: Print IP address
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: Droplet IP address is {{ my_droplet.data.ip_address }}

    - name: Add A record with route53
      community.aws.route53:
        aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
        state: present
        zone: growthpath.com.au
        record: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        type: A
        ttl: 7200
        value: "{{ my_droplet.data.ip_address }}"
        wait: yes
```

## Example inventory file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    test-dear1.growthpath.com.au:
      droplet_name: test-dear1
      ansible_host: test-dear1.growthpath.com.au
```

ansible-playbook  -i inventory_aws_test.yml -v create_new_droplet.yml